# Find the value of $x$ such that the matrix represents a projection

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Given the operator $P: \Bbb {R^3} \to \Bbb {R^3}$, whose matrix in the standard base is 
\begin{equation*}
P_{3,3} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & -1/2 & 1/2 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
-1/2 & -1/2 & x 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Find x such that P is a projection.
The author proposed a solution by claiming that we want $P^2=P$, but didn't explain why and by solving the equation we obtain $x=\frac32$ but didn't really explain the reason for that equation, or maybe there is a more intuitive way to solve this exercise.

Comment: What do you mean by "claiming that we want $P^2 = P$, **but didn't explain why**"? What is your definition of projection?

Comment: I assume it is a projection onto a plane in $\Bbb R^3$, and the author of the exercise claimed that to start a solution, but didn't explain it, so I don't really know what he meant.

Comment: @zastenAmir Ask yourself: what would happen if we again project ($P$) the projection ($Pv$)?

Comment: The result would be $P(Pv)=P(v)$, because it has already been projected, so I have obtained such equation and the rest is multiplication of matrices. Thank you

Comment: By definition, a projection operator $P$ satisfies $P^2=P$. There isn't much more to it than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to  @Anurag A, for helping me to understand the question and the solution proposed by the author of this exercise.
We have the projection operator $P$ which transforms a vector $v$ so that $P(v)=P(v) \in \Bbb R^3$, so we can take the projection again $P(P(v))=P(v)$ and in terms of matrices we obtain $P^2=P$ for any $v \in \Bbb R^3$
\begin{equation*}
P*P = 
\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & -1/2 & 1/2 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
-1/2 & -1/2 & x 
\end{pmatrix}^2=\begin{pmatrix}
1/2 & -1/2 & 1/2 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 \\
-1/2 & -1/2 & x 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}
Therefore, $x=\frac32$ satisfies the equation.